# scroll down using htmlUnitDriver

Tags: java, selenium, testing, htmlunit-driver

I am working on htmlUnitDriver. I have tried so many method to scroll down the page but I didn't get any solution. Does anybody out there know how to scroll the page using HTML Unit drivers? I tried with `actions` and `executeScript` but didn't work.

Thanks

Comment: Can you paste your code, what you have tried?